# Fast Transfer Of Rows Between Databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, optimization, sql-server-ce

I am using a SQL CE (4.0) database as a local cache for records from a specific view in a main SQL Server (Express 2014). Each iteration of my algorithm I want to validate the local cache and update it with the necessary records from the main server.

My current solutions serializes a DataTable containing the rows (using the SyncFramework surrogate) and brings it over via WCF to be deserialized and inserted into the cache. The reasoning was to only require a single port for WCF to be opened. The problem is that this is too slow for my purposes.

If I relax the single port requirement, could I get better performance from another method?

Comment: Web API with JSON and use SqlCeBulkCopy to insert fast or TableDirect ADO api on client.

Answer (score 0):

No, enabling more than one port wouldn't increase the performance of the data transmission or processing.
A TCP port is not a physical resource that can be stressed, but a logical construct that identifies a specific process or a type of service.

Some things that you can do to improve the performance of the communication between client and server:

- Use a much faster binding: Like NetTcpBinding or NetNamedPipeBinding.
- Compress the data before sending it to the server in order to transmit less information from the client to the server. (Using a DataTable might not be the best strategy).
- Make the service call asynchronously. So you don't wait for a server response to continue working on the client end.
- Fine tune WCF to accept more connections in parallel.
- Use self hosting services to avoid the IIS overhead if you don't need it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was quite clear. I do only need the one port, I agree.

I'm looking for fundamentally different solutions. Could I do straight ADO over the network? This would bypass WCF serialization entirely.

Comment: You can do direct ADO and the performance will increase for sure. But that's up to your architectural decisions and depends on your non functional requirements. One thing I totally recommend is to abstract the caching layer detaching the caching strategy from the business rules. So you can later switch it to a better faster or scalable solution up to your needs.